# Replication Database and settings snapshot agent

Tags: sql-server, authentication, replication

I have trivial question related with transactional publication with updatable subscriptions.

I created on PCA Publication with this type, choose database, table but I have problem with configuration snapshot agent. I don't know what to enter in field Process account ( in Snapshot Agent ). I am helpless but I don't know idea...

Computer Name: Frankly
Database: Frankly-PC\Frankly ( SQL Server 10.50.1600 - test )

I am loggin to database by means of log=test, pass=test.

I greet.

PS. This is screen:

http://postimage.org/image/lr4o0thbn/

Help me...

Answer (score 0):

According to [Replication Agent Security Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151868.aspx):

> Snapshot Agent
>
> The Windows account under which the agent runs is used when it makes
>   connections to the Distributor. This account must:
>
> - At minimum, be a member of the db_owner fixed database role in the distribution database.
> - Have read, write, and modify permissions on the snapshot share.
>
> The account that is used to connect to the Publisher must at minimum
>   be a member of the db_owner fixed database role in the publication
>   database.

Comment: Okay, When I to enter in field "process acount: Frankly-PC\Frankly " <- this is my login to database ( no include password ( Windows Authentication ) ) is error: Unable to start execution of step 2 (reason: Error authenticating proxy Frankly-PC\Frankly, system error: Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.).  The step failed.